# compare the 0 index values in nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

I have a nested list

```
[[511  45]
 [510 200]
 [509 152]
 [509 150]
 [509 149]
 [507 200]
 [507 150]
 [507 149]
 [506 152]]
```

So here I want to comapare the "0" indices values , if the value is equal print the "1" indices
Like

> [509 152] [509 150] [509 149]

then print

152 150 149

Comment: Is the list guaranteed to be sorted by the first element? If not, then what do you want to compare? All others, or only neighbours?

Comment: and for the case of [509 150] [509 149] [507 200] [507 150] what do you expect to get for the middle case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by List comprehension :

```
nested_list = [[511,  45],
 [510, 200],
 [509, 152],
 [509, 150],
 [509, 149],
 [507, 200],
 [507, 150],
 [507, 149],
 [506, 152]]

temp = set(map(lambda i : i[0], nested_list))
res =  [{i : [j[1] for j in nested_list if j[0] == i]} for i in temp] 
print(str(res))
```

Your output would be :

> [{506: [152]}, {507: [200, 150, 149]}, {509: [152, 150, 149]}, {510:
> [200]}, {511: [45]}]

Comment: The print output he showed as an example only had the second value of each sub array. So I don't think this is what he wants (But I'm not sure so no downvote from me)

Comment: @TheGrandJ You can edit the "res" variable in my solution to display whatever values are required in the output. For the output shown in the question, you can just replace `{i : [j[1] for j in nested_list if j[0] == i]}` with `[j[1] for j in nested_list if j[0] == i]`

Comment: @SwathiMudda I want the similar output but not in form of set/tuple/list

Comment: @KrupaliMistry Do you mean, instead of {509: [152, 150, 149]}, you want just [152, 150, 149] ? Refer to my earlier comment. You can remove the "i" from the "res".

Comment: No just [506: [152], 507: [200, 150, 149], 509: [152, 150, 149], 510: [200], 511: [45]]

Comment: @KrupaliMistry OH that is what you wanted. Please update your question

Comment: @TheGrandJ Swathis's answer matches with what I wanted to do further with the values.

Comment: @KrupaliMistry Assuming you want a dict, you can use ```res =  {i : [j[1] for j in nested_list if j[0] == i] for i in temp}``` , the output would be : {506: [152], 507: [200, 150, 149], 509: [152, 150, 149], 510: [200], 511: [45]}

Comment: @KrupaliMistry Yes but how were we meant to know that? You asked for the values but did not show what format or what to do in edge cases. You didn't even mention you wanted individual results too. Your question is not clear and makes it hard to get what you want. SO PLEASE update your question with what you actually want and/or the full expected result.

Comment: @TheGrandJ I just wanted the values , I didn't wanted to mention what I would further do with it.

Answer (score 0):

We first grab a counter for the amount of arrays in the list

```
for x in range(len(varList))
```

Then we check if the index 0 of the current sub array matches the next one. On a match we print.

```
   if varList[x][0] = varList[x+1][0]
       print(varList[x][1])
```

then in the case we do not get a match we will check the previous one for a match. If this succeeds then we will print the result of the current sub array.

```
   elif varList[x][0] = varList[x-1][0]
       print(varList[x][1])
```

I have assumed here that you want all matches regardless of direction of match (ie next to or behind)